# Azure Active Directory LDAP password change

Tags: java, ldap, azure-active-directory

i've connected successfull to Azure Active Directory trough LDAP protocol with JAVA, i'm able to get users and their attributes.

I'm trying to change users's password but everytime i try to do it i receive this error from LDAP: "error code 50 - 00000005: SecErr: DSID-031A1256, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0"

I've checked that the user and credential used for password reset have Administrative right (Global Administrator on Azure).

I've noticed that same problems appears when using LDAP GUI client: it's not possible to change user password because of insufficient right.
I'm struggling on how to do it but i've tried quite all things...
Have you got any suggestions?
Thank You

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: You can change the user password by calling MS graph api.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http